# How should I organize 2D sprites?

Tags: unity

I'm using a Unity Tilemap in my 2D game, and I have several hundred 32x32 sprites.  Most of the examples I've seen using sprites have a few consolidated sprite sheets that contain all of the game's sprites.  For instance, I'd have a few 1024x1024 sprite sheets that contain all of my game's sprites. 
 Those examples all say that the reason to do it this way is that performance is improved when sprites are packed together like that.

The problem with these large consolidated sprite sheets is that it's difficult to find the sprites that I want when I'm making a tile pallet or animated/scripted sprite.

For example, I have two 1024x1024 sprite sheets called "House Interior 1" and "House Interior 2" that contain all my walls, floors, furniture, doors, windows, and miscellaneous interior objects.  Now I want to create one Unity tile pallet that has only tiles for western-style houses and one tile pallet that has only tiles for eastern-style houses.  Each tile pallet is going to require some, but not all, sprites from both of my sprite sheets (House Interior 1 and House Interior 2).  Additionally, I want to create some animated tiles.  Each animated tile will use a few sprites from somewhere in the middle of one of the large sprite sheets.

My problem is that each sprite sheet image has so many child sprites that it becomes very tedious and time consuming to visually scan through each huge sprite sheet to find the tiles I want, and then drag each of them individually onto my tile pallet.  Making animated tiles results in the same problem because when I assign each animation frame, I have to find the correct sprite from a huge list of sprites that are named `House Interior_1`, `House Interior_2`, `House Interior_3`, and so on.

I'd like to have smaller sprite sheets that only contain one specific type of sprite, rather than huge sprite sheets of often unrelated sprites.  For example, I'd like to have one sprite sheet that has only masonry walls, one that has only brick walls, one that has only the animation frames of a fireplace, and so on.  That way it'll be easier to build up Unity tile pallets by dragging several sprite sheets into the tile pallet in the Inspector, and it'll be easier to find my animated tiles because I can easily find the sprites named `Fireplace_1`, `Fireplace_2`, and `Fireplace_3`.

So my questions are:

- How big of a performance hit will I experience if I don't pack my tiles together into a few big spritesheets?  Is it even worth taking this into account considering modern devices are so powerful compared to what is necessary to do sprite-based graphics?
- Is this a case of balancing the pros and cons of both methods, or is it generally strongly recommended that I large consolidated sprite sheets?

Comment: The nice thing about Unity is that it can pack your sprite sheets for you. You can arrange them in however many images you want, and then assign the images to be packed together and get the benefits of packing without the overhead of having to manage all of the sprites together in one big mess.

Comment: In my experience with sprites it was easier to keep sprites in separate files each, then use unity's atlas tool that auto consolidates them. BTW there are 2 tools (old and new). The old one uses a text field on each sprite to group them, the new one is an asset that can add folders to be grouped in one atlas. In both cases you continue to use sprites as separate files but Unity creates atlases "behind the scene".

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I've briefly seen sprite atlases before, but I never really paid too much attention to them.  I'll definitely look into it more thoroughly now.